# memset causes hanging in specific devices

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, memset

I am investigating hanging issue for specific Android devices(in this question, Samsung Galaxy 920S). Using `ndk-gdb` I could catch the blocking point.

The blocked point is like this:

```
char* temp = (char*) StartAddress;
memset (temp, 0, 0x1000);
```

value of `temp` was `0xa720d000` and the mapping was like this:
(used `info proc mappings`)

```
    Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
    ...
    0xa71da000 0xa71dc000     0x2000        0x0
    0xa71dc000 0xa71e0000     0x4000        0x0
    0xa71f0000 0xa7210000    0x20000        0x0
    0xa7210000 0xa7218000     0x8000        0x0
    ...
```

So that means I can write to that address, right? But it is hangging. Any ideas that could explain the situation?

Comment: Maybe the mapped region is read-only

Comment: Nothing which says you can write to that address.

Comment: @geza ok, I checked maps file and it has `rw-p`

Comment: If it doesn't crash, how do you know that's the problem? Is it on the main thread? Maybe some other thread is blocked, not this one.

Comment: @Peter: the line which begins with `0xa71f0000` means that (and OP says it's mapped with write access).

Comment: @geza I can see what happens in asm level. And some point it cannot process even single operation.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6pDmHh1D here is some asm code and process is stuck at point where I marked

Comment: What's the value of `r3`? If you issue `si` in gdb, does it hang (no crash, just you don't get the prompt back)?

Comment: for `memset(dst, val, len)`, r0 and r1 is `val` and r2 is `len` and r3 is `dst`. And si command also hangs.

Comment: And the hanging what I say is it won't crash and I cannot get prompt back.

Comment: Then it is more of a debugger/OS problem I think. android gdb is very unreliable in my opinion. If it cannot write to a memory region, it should crash. What happens, if you put `__android_log_print` around the `memset`, and run the app without gdb? Is it really the case, that a log before `memset` is printed, but the log after it isn't?

Comment: And the value of R3 at the point of failure?

Comment: @geza yes, I also guess that maybe the problem is not about the code itself. This happens in just small list of devices. I wanted to know any related issues to chipset or kernels. I investigated the issue because some users of my app reported the freezing/hanging, not crash.

Comment: @Surt As mentioned in question, destination address seems valid and i can see the pointed value through debugger.

Comment: what kind of data is stored in that area of memory? if it has anything to do with control of the ongoing process, unusual behavior is not unexpected.

Comment: @Red.Wave it is a kind of memory pool for custom memory management. Actually it is inside [ChakraCore's pal module](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/tree/master/pal). It works without a problem in Mac, Windows, iOS and most of Android devices.

Comment: @geza that code came from [https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/v1.8.0/pal/src/map/virtual.cpp#L1188](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/v1.8.0/pal/src/map/virtual.cpp#L1188). And the `StartBoundary` value is `mmap`ed or `mprotect`ed before calling `memset`. At the problem situation, `mprotect` was called. So I changed a flag to be calling mmap and problem solved. I still do not know why but I guess this OS did not handle invalid memory access properly.